# Argument statement by itself

Tags: javascript, typescript

I was reading the excellent book Effective TypeScript (by Dan Vanderkam) and in one example he had a line that was confusing to me. It was seemingly fundamentally basic but it just didn't make any sense to me. What is the purpose of the `shape;` statement below? And why repeat it? Is it a typo?

```js
interface Square {
  kind: 'square';
  width: number;
}
interface Rectangle {
  kind: 'rectangle';
  height: number;
  width: number;
}
type Shape = Square | Rectangle;

function calculateArea(shape: Shape) {
  if (shape.kind === 'rectangle') {
    shape;  // what does this even do?
    return shape.width * shape.height;
  } else {
    shape;  // ???
    return shape.width * shape.width;
  }
}
```

Comment: For the first look it does not make any sense. I guess it is a typo.

Comment: Yeah I would have thought so too but then I would have thought such as simple and glaring mistake would have showed up on the publisher's errata page (https://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=0636920261544)

Comment: I just checked that book and what I can see is it is there just for explain the title `You Cannot Check TypeScript Types at Runtime`. So the `shape;` is just their so that the author was able to add a comment to that line which explain the type of the parameter `shape` inside the block.

Comment: You're probably correct, just seems like a comment by itself would have sufficed (and been less confusing).

Answer (score 1):

My bad, I didn't read the book's preface. The author writes:

> I will occasionally introduce no-op statements to indicate the type of
> a variable on a specific line of code:

```js
function foo(x: string | string[]) {
  if (Array.isArray(x)) {
    x; // Type is string[]
  } else {
    x; // Type is string
  }
}
```

> The `x;` lines are only there to demonstrate the type in each branch of the conditional. You don’t need to (and shouldn’t) include statements like this in your own code.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a typo. Since this `shape` thing cause no side effect, not changing anything.  Deleting it should be 100% fine.